# How to compare 2 'created_at' dates in Laravel 4.2 Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, laravel-4, jenssegers-mongodb

In my application the user can view an image and click on the 'next' or 'previous' photo button. Currently, the logic for pulling the next / previous image urls is based on the `'created_at'` field. I am trying to pick all documents from my collection where the `'created_at'` date is greater than the current resource's (being viewed by the user) value. However, the first document that is returned has the same `'created_at'` value as my current resource's `'created_at'` field.

**Eloquent Query:**

```
$photos = Photo::where('_id', '!=', $this->_id)
                 ->where('created_at', '>', $this->created_at)
                 ->orderBy('created_at', 'ASC');
```

**Using:**

- Laravel 4.2
   - Mongodb 2.6.10
   - Library: jenssegers/mongodb 2.*

Any help will be much appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

i have one idea to your question....

1)add viewed_at column in photo table

2)onlcik function with update table value 'viewd_column' using  date('Y-m-d H:i:s');  via ajax when user click image or next button

3)compare the created_at with viewed_at like below query

u need jquery onclick function here...for when user view the image that time the value stored  in your table ..if u have created_at column...create another one column viewed_at now u can update that table column when user click that source image..then now u can get the click date from viewed_at column... now compare both date

```
$photos = Photo::where('_id', '!=', $this->_id)
             ->where('created_at', '>',  $this->viewed_at)
             ->orderBy('created_at', 'ASC');
```

Its help to u.. thank u .. all the best.. if u have doubt ask to me.. i will help u..